# How can I highlight the BarButton in navigation bar without tapping it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Typically, the UIBarButtonItem will be highlighted when we tap it.

However, I intend to show the users that the action is automatically done for them when the view is loaded after 4 sec.

So I want to highlight the Button without tapping it.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `UIVIew` object such as a `UIButton`, you can either use the following code [Glow category on UIView that adds support for making views glow](https://github.com/thesecretlab/UIView-Glow) or use [this example](http://benscheirman.com/2011/09/creating-a-glow-effect-for-uilabel-and-uibutton).

If you are using the first one, you can just call `startGlowing` and `stopGlowing`. When you call `startGlowing`, the view will start to pulse with a soft light, this effect is removed when `stopGlowing` is called. Check [this](http://blog.secretlab.com.au/2012/06/23/glowing/).

For `UIBarButtonItem`, you might have to use [the solution provided here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1657281?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: What if the UIBarButton is initialized with one of the systemitem style, such as UIBarButtonSystemItem Camera

Comment: You cant use the above with bar button item, for that I have added another link. Check it. If you want to use the other methods, you might have add a UIView as a subview on the bar button item and show the animation on the UIVIew instead of button.